# BS4 to find embedded ID number

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BS4 to find ID numbers that are embedded in html. However, they aren't really attached to anything I'm used to working with, like a tag or the like. I've looked at how to pull something from a div class, but haven't had success with that either. Below is what soup looks like after I collect the html:

```
<div class="result-bio">
<div class="profile-image">
<img class="search-image load-member-profile" ng-click="results.loadProfile(result.UGuid)"
 ng-src="http://file.asdf.org/profile/picture.ashx?id=9091a557-fd44-44be-9468-9386d90a39b8" 
 src="http://file.asdf.org/profile/picture.ashx?id=9091a557-fd44-44be-9468-9386d90a39b8"/>
</div>
```

The code I have been attempting is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
ID_Numbers = []
for IDs in soup.find_all('div', string='http'):
    ID_Numbers.append(IDs.text)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this? I imagine I will have to strip later, but really all I want is that id=xxxx value embedded in there. I've tried most of the solutions I've seen on stack with no success. Thanks!

Comment: Why not get the `src` attribute from `img`?

Comment: @match If I'm understanding you correctly that would be find_all('img', string='ng-src')?

Comment: Get the entire string (the src) and then use regex, or even str.split() to get the id.

Comment: @agastya for some reason running find_all('div', string='src') returns an empty list. Any idea why? Pretty much whatever I try returns an empty list

Comment: src is not a string, but a feature of html. string= is used to match text that is displayed (for eg. text in 'p' element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find all the image elements, then loop over these elements to get the source for each image. Then, simply break the src down to get the id.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source, features='html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('img'):
    src = i['src']
    try:
        id = src.split('?id=')[1]
        print(id)
    except(IndexError):
        continue
```

Here, I have split the src to get the id, but in more complicated cases you may need to use regex.

Comment: This seems to be very close. When I run it as is, I get that [1] is out of range, but running [0] gives me about 10 lines that I don't want of ID's stripped out and then on to the website I want as: /sites/new/www.asdf.org/modules/custom/asco_memdir2/app/images/badge_pubs.png
`

Comment: Is the format for all the src(s) the same (as in "link?id=id_code"), or are they different?

Comment: They are the same. The first 10 links arise just because they are ID numbers in the same format, just not ones I am interested in. The rest follow the same format though. The issue is that I get the first part of the ID number that has been stripped and not that actual number I want if that makes sense

Comment: In that case a try except statement will work. I have edited my answer. Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! One final question for you - I tried doing a similar thing but by having an if statement stating: if 'http://file.asdf.org/profile/picture.ashx' in src:
and then performing the split. This worked, but the first 19 prints were <variable at xxx> and then after those I got my ID numbers. Any idea why? Thank you SO much for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I'll need more details here. Can you post the first 19 prints before the split (if, of course, the data is not confidential)?

Comment: it just says: <built-in function id> for the first 20 entries or so. Then it gives the ID numbers. Thanks!

Comment: I'm really not sure. Perhaps the src's are like that. Oh, and I just saw the other answer (by Shashishekhar) and I think his idea of using urllib's urlsplit module is a really good one. The method will work across the board, and is more flexible than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt `[urlparse][1]` library like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlsplit 

html_doc = """
<div class="result-bio">
<div class="profile-image">
<img class="search-image load-member-profile" ng-click="results.loadProfile(result.UGuid)"
 ng-src="http://file.asdf.org/profile/picture.ashx?id=9091a557-fd44-44be-9468-9386d90a39b8" 
 src="http://file.asdf.org/profile/picture.ashx?id=9091a557-fd44-44be-9468-9386d90a39b8"/>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
images = soup.findAll('img')
ids = []
for i in images:
    parsed = urlsplit(i['src'])
    id = parsed.query.replace("id=", "")
    ids.append(id)
print(ids)
```

This gave me output:-

```
['9091a557-fd44-44be-9468-9386d90a39b8']
```